# Can I customize the virtual keyboard for an input field

Tags: html, cordova

Can I customize the virtual keyboard for an input field? Can I do it in browser or in PhoneGap?

Comment: Do you need customize key for ios or android

Comment: Mainly for Android, but it will be good if the solution works for iOS too.